# Program Termination error while printing the array

Tags: c, arrays

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int n, i;
  char arr[20];
  clrscr();
  printf("Enter size of array(<=20)");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Enter array");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%s", &arr[i]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%s", arr[i]);
  }

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

The program does not prints the array 
and instead shows 
**Program termination** message

[The image shows the program termiantion message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrM11.png)

Comment: @ajas Paunikar The conversion specifier %s is used with character arrays that contain strings. You are using this specifier with scalar objects of the type char.

Comment: `char arr[20];` does not mean an array of 20 strings, with each string being big enough to hold the entire text of "Harry Potter And The Sorcerer's Stone". You cannot expect to be able to enter the entire text of each Harry Potter book in response to "Enter Array", and have it fit inside your `char arr[20];`. C does not work this way.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: @RajasPaunikar We cannot tell you what to do if we don't know what exactly your program is supposed to do. You want an array of number or an array of strings or an array of characters or ...?

Comment: I wanted the program to read the array and then print it.
I changed the %s to %c from 
printf("%s" , arr[i]);

Now it works 
Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the line

`printf("%s", arr[i]);`.

If you change this line to

`printf("%c", arr[i]);`

then it will work because `%s` is used with character arrays that contain strings

I am just giving the solution for your program termination. Still we can do some modification in your code.

Thanks